# Tracking Email Opens with GTM Event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I'd like to trigger an event to identify when an image has been served upon visiting a site.

The goal is to use this event for email open tracking. I already have a tracking pixel embedded in the email that served from my website each time the user opens the email.

I have the event set up to store the 'Label' = a variable that contains the query string from the URL referre. This should in theory capture the utm parameters from the URL, for example:

```
website.com/1x1tracker.gif?utm_source=email&utm_campaign=emailcampaign1&utm_content=welcomeemail
```

Where I am getting stuck is the trigger for the event. For a normal image viewing event I could just do something with an 'Element Visible' trigger and be done with it, but since the image is requested from the website via the email client, no one actually visits the site.

Curious to hear thoughts on how I can get this event to be triggered by someone opening the email and having the request for the image sent to my site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to track email opens with GTM since it only works in a DOM environment and requires some Javascript to run on the page.
However, you can send events to Google Analytics through Measurement Protocol based on the parameters in your pixel URL. Google provides a sample code to do that [on the help pages.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email)